# Need help removing Pages URI

Tags: pages, page-uri

I'm using the Pages module. In one entry, I created a Pages URI just to test something. Now I want to remove the URI for that entry, but I can't. It seems to be forcing me to populate the Pages URI field, but I want it blank, like it was when I initially created the entry.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds odd - but you can remove the page via **Add-on → Modules → Pages**.